# Javascript freezes after adding more than one function while using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

I was trying to make a snake game, I was just beginning to start animating my character by following code :

```js
var head = document.getElementById("snakehead");
var pos = 0;
var direction = "right";
var val_type = "px";
var speed = 50;
var run = setInterval(move_right, speed);

function move_right() {
  head.style.left = pos + val_type; //Concatination of value and "px" using "+"
  pos += 10;
  if (pos > 980) {
    pos = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#body-holder {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#header {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

#score {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

#playfield {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: solid 10px white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#snakehead {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="body-holder">
    <div id="header">
      <span id="title">Snake Game</span>
      <span id="score">Score : 00</span>
    </div>
    <div id="playfield">
      <div id="snakehead"></div>
      <div id="body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and this runs well, but whenever I created any other function, it just stops running that setInterval command and the animation stops, like I added this simple function to just test :

```
function hi{
    alert("Hello World!!");
}
```

Even adding this function or even an empty function freezes the whole javascript, then even if I call that `hi()` function later on then still it doesn't work! Not even a normal alert function works at top of code then!!

Comment: Have you debugged your code? If yes, you would have seen that your function declaration is wrong, it is missing `()`

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing `()` in your function.

Change `function hi{` to `function hi() {` then your application will work.